# Webkit doesn't provide an XML declaration with serializeToString

Tags: javascript, xml, webkit, xmlserializer

The following code should `alert` the exact same as the input:

```
var string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\n<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Target="media/image3.png" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Id="rId8"/></Relationships>';

var xml = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(string, 'text/xml');

// Manipulate the DOM / do something...

var newString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
alert(newString);
```

However, under [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit), it removes the XML declaration:

[image]

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6FdBa/) (try it on [safari](/questions/tagged/safari) or [air](/questions/tagged/air)).

I've found [a bug on Webkit](http://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25206) that seems to go with this story.

How can I make sure my `newString` has the same XML declaration it was given to begin with in `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the existence of a declaration, and explicitly add one if none is found:

```
if(newString.indexOf('<?xml') !== 0)
    newString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\n' + newString;
```

Here's [an updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6FdBa/2/).

Alternatively, to use the input string's declaration:

```
if(newString.indexOf('<?xml') !== 0)
    newString = string.substring(0, string.indexOf('\n')) + newString;
```

[Another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6FdBa/3/).